# Why does the pygtk callback on a clicked ToolButton executed twice when clicked once

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've got a simple callback function which switches the label of a PyGTK button:

```
def langSelectHandler(self, widget, callback_data=None):
    if self.lang == "fr":
        self.lang = "de"
        print "changed to de"
        widget.set_label("Deutsch")
    else:
        self.lang = "fr"
        print "changed to fr"
        widget.set_label("Français")
```

The button is connected like this:

```
self.langSelect.connect("clicked", self.langSelectHandler)
```

(I verified the duplicate call using random numbers generated each call, they were different)
My problem is, that the callback gets executed twice, and therefore switches back to its old value, so no change is visible. Why the hell is that the case and how can this be prevented?

Thanks,
Julian

Comment: It shouldn't. I don't know PyGtk well, but maybe you are using connect somehow twice?

Comment: thanks, it was a "blind" connect from inside my glade file I forgot while coding :) I just started today with gtk programming, so It's a fairly new topic to me

Comment: @Julian If you solved the problem, you should post the solution as an answer to your question and then 'accept' the answer. This can make it easier for other users to find the solution, and see that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out in my comment (see the 2nd entry below the post), I made a connect via the code as well as via glade which lead to the 2 calls. If you ran into a similar or same problem just check that.